# Find sum of a finite nested radical $ \sqrt{2012+\sqrt{2012+\sqrt{2012+\cdots}}} $ 2012 times

Tags: sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

$$ \sqrt{2012+\sqrt{2012+\sqrt{2012+\cdots}}} $$

This is not an infinite series but is limited to the **2012th term**. How can this expression be simplified?

Comment: Why do you think it can be?  You can compute an approximate value.  It will be very close to the limit, which is $\frac 12(1+\sqrt{8049})$

Comment: I checked using Python and Ross Milikan is right. It does converge if infinite

Comment: The sum was given by one of my teacher. We are not allowed to use calculator or any other device.

Comment: what do you mean by simplified?

Comment: If we define a sequence $(u_n)$, we have $u_1=\sqrt{2012}$ and $u_{n+1}^2=2012 + u_n$. We need to compute $u_{2012}$... Not sure it helps a lot to find a closed form.

Comment: You can simplify it by finite series formula it will be better for limited number of series

Comment: what counts as simpler? It's unclear what you're asking

Comment: There is not much point for a closed form. Since the convergence is exponential. Your nested radical with 2012 terms differ from the limit $\frac12(1 + \sqrt{8049})$ for a extremely small amount. My rough estimate is about $6 \times 10^{-3938}$. an approximate accurate up to a few thousand digits should be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x_n = \sqrt{2012 + x_{n-1}} \iff x_n^2 = 2012 + x_{n-1} \iff x_n^2 - 2012 = x_{n-1}$$
And setting $$x_{0} = 0 $$ yields the relation $$x_1^2 - 2012 = 0 \therefore (x_2^2 - 2012)^2 - 2012 = 0 \therefore ((x_3^2 - 2012)^2 - 2012)^2 - 2012 = 0$$ which you can keep unravelling until you get a polynomial equation in $x_{2012}$, and maybe a CAS can then express a nice closed form solution for the roots of that polynomial (which is somehow simpler than what you wrote). Otherwise you can solve it *approximately* as Ross Milikan did.

The way his solution works is that you notice that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $u_n$ becomes the same as $u_{n-1}$ so you then get the equation $$x_\infty^2 - x_\infty - 2012 = 0$$ which is a quadratic equation you can solve to get $$x_\infty = {1 \over 2}(1 + \sqrt{8049}) $$ and it should be the case that $x_{2012} \approx x_\infty \approx 45$.